# Tricky detection of href attribute with Regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Given the following html code I want to detect the real href of the link. You see that I have a "fake" href in the div too.

```
$html = '
<a  class="test">simple text</a>
<div data-href="yahoo.com">yahoo in div</div>
<a class="blabla"   href="google.com">google</a>';

preg_match("'<a.*?href=[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]'si", $html, $output);
```

What I got now is yahoo.com but this is not what I need.. I want to receive google.com.

Do you have any ideeas ?

Comment: If you force a blank space after the `<a` it will work fine: `"'<a\ [^>]*href=[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]'si"`

Comment: I'm still getting yahoo even with the blank space

Comment: works perfect. Thanks Jordi ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?<=href=")(\w+)\.\w+(?=">\1[^ ])
```

Check: https://regex101.com/r/nB1wP4/5

Answer (score 0):

I would try simplify. Try it https://regex101.com/r/oU6kR8/1

```
\shref="([a-z.\/:]+)"
```